# what is the probability of having at least one 3 consecutive wins in 10 rolls?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

This is probably quite a simple question but here I go..
Suppose you are going to roll a six-sided (fair) die N times, what is the probability that you will get at least one a number 4 consecutive in a row?
Hopefully that's clear enough but as an example, in 10 rolls you may get:
1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3,8,9,2
With the 4s making 1 triple  consecutive rolls.

1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3,2,1,2
With the 4s making 2 triple  consecutive rolls.

4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 3,3,1,2
With the 4s making 2 triple

Thanks!

Comment: Easier, I expect, to count the sequences in which no $XXX$ occurs.  There should be a simple recursion that lets you count these. (Hint:  use the fact that any such sequence must end in either $YX$ or $YXX$).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: So what the answer?